# Subjonctif ou conditionnel après « jusqu'à ce que » mais avant « si » ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, conditionnel

Dans une phrase comme:

> S'il restait peu de temps, je me dépêcherais jusqu'à ce que je finisse.

devrait-on utiliser le subjonctif ou le conditionnel pour le verbe « finir » ? Normalement, on utilise le conditionnel avec « si », comme dans:

> S'il restait peu de temps, je me dépêcherais et je finirais.

, mais le subjonctif après « jusqu'à »:

> Je me dépêche jusqu'à ce que je finisse.

Est-ce que l'un a plus de priorité que l'autre? Est-ce qu'on peut mettre n'importe lequel? Ou est-ce que quelque chose comme le « subjonctif conditionnel » (« <strike>finisserais</strike> ») existe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Jusqu'à ce que* requiert le subjonctif dans tous les cas, quel que soit le reste de la phrase. Vos trois phrases sont grammaticalement correctes telles que vous les avez écrites.

Cette [page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif) de la Wikipédia en français contient une liste des conjonctions qui requièrent (sans condition) le subjonctif. On y trouve, entre autres: *à condition que, de peur que, pourvu que, à moins que, de sorte que, à supposer que, en attendant que, afin que, **jusqu’à ce que**, quoi que* ...

Il n'existe pas à ma connaissance de "subjonctif conditionnel". Mais le subjonctif contient déjà une notion d'incertitude, ce qui rend inutile de le combiner avec un conditionnel. D'après l'article sur le mode subjonctif de la [Wikipédia en français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif): *Le subjonctif est un mode grammatical exprimant un fait pensé ou imaginé (opinion, fait irréel, **incertain ou simplement envisagé**), par contraste avec l'indicatif, qui est censé rapporter les faits réels.*